# How likely is it to guess three numbers?

Tags: probability

In the Irish lottery if you guess three numbers correctly you win 576x your original stake and there are 12 draws a week.

My questions is: *How likely is it, over the course of two years (104 weeks or 1248 draws) that I will guess the numbers correctly?*

The rules are as follows:

- you can only choose numbers between 1-49
- you can only choose three of these numbers
- the total draw will produce 6 numbers, yet only the three you have chosen need to match

So over two years, how likely will I be to win? Thanks :)

Comment: If what Regret asks has a positive answer then no wonder how come poor Irland got into so terrible economical problem in the last years!

Comment: Yes. Out of the 6 you need to guess only 3, in any order. For example, say I guess numbers 1,2 and 3 and the numbers drawn are 6,3,2,5,4,1 I would still win

Comment: And you'd win times $\;576\;$ what you bought?! Well, those guys are really nice since you have one out of $\;18,424\;$ chances to win . I know no national lottey with such big risk-profit odds

Comment: At the risk of appearing chippy, I will point out that this is **not** how the Irish lottery works in real life.

Comment: On the other hand, when it was launched in 1988, the draw was initially made from only 36 numbers. So once the jackpot reached a sufficient level (about £1.7 million), the expected value of buying every combination became positive (and non-trivial). You can guess what happened next: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Lottery_%28Ireland%29#History_of_Lotto

Answer (score 1):

At a given draw you are choosing one of ${49\choose3}=18424$ triples at random. Since $6$ numbers will be drawn there are ${6\choose3}=20$ successful triples. It follows that the probability $p$ of a success in one draw is given by
$$p={20\over18424}\doteq0.00108554\ .$$
The probability $q$ that you fail in all of 1248 draws is therefore given by
$$q=(1-p)^{1248}\doteq0.25782\ .$$
Therefore you can count on succeeding at least once in two years with probability $1-q\doteq0.74218$.

Answer (score 0):

The chance of getting the first number right is $\frac6{49}$, the second one is $\frac5{49}$ and third one is $\frac4{49}$. the product of these 3 fractions gives you the probability of winning a draw on a single attempt. If you have $1248$ draws, multiply this fraction by the same to get the probability of winning $1$ (or more) draws over $2$ years.

Note:
If numbers can not be repeated, use $49$, $48$ and $47$ as denominators, instead of $49$ all $3$ times.

Assuming numbers can be repeated, this gives a result of about $1.2$, which means you can be pretty sure of winning once in $2$ years. $576$ times profit is still an inadequate amount for $1248$ tries, but its worth trying your luck.